# Rendering translated phrase on frontend? (Trouble with exporting phrase from backend)

Tags: node.js

I'm using Google's Cloud Translation API to translate some text on the backend, which I then want to render on the frontend. However, I'm having trouble exporting the translated phrase. This is the code copy/pasted from the docs; the only thing that I added was the export.

```
const text = "text";
const target = "en";
translate.translate(text, target)
  .then((results) => {
    let translations = results[0];
    translations = Array.isArray(translations) ? translations : [translations];

    console.log('Translations:');
    translations.forEach((translation, i) => {
      console.log(`${text[i]} => (${target}) ${translation}`);
    });

    module.exports = translations;

  })

  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

Then, in my routes.js file, I have:

```
var translate = require('../translate');

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    var translate = translate;
    console.log(translate);
    res.render('index', { 'translate': translate });
});
```

Printing translate to the console produces "undefined."

Comment: Since `translate.translate` is an async operation, `module.exports` doesn't have any data initially and is thus set to `undefined` when the file is required. Try returning a `function` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `translate.translate` is an async operation, `module.exports` doesn't have any data initially and is thus set to `undefined` when the file is required. Try returning a `function` instead. Like this -

*translate.js*

```
const text = "text";

const target = "en";

module.exports = function() {
  return translate.translate(text, target)
    .then(results => {

      let translations = results[0];

      translations = Array.isArray(translations) ? translations : [translations];

      console.log('Translations:');

      translations.forEach((translation, i) => {
        console.log(`${text[i]} => (${target}) ${translation}`);
      });

      return Promise.resolve(translations);
    });
};
```

*routes.js*

```
const translate = require('../translate');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {

  translate()
    .then(translations => {
      res.render('index', { 'translate': translations });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    });
});
```